# IMAP folder named Notes does not appear in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

I have a folder on my IMAP server named « Notes ».

I have deactivated the use of the IMAP account by the Notes.app, but the folder is still not visible in Mail.app.

Is there a way to have this folder displayed as a normal folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advent of Mountain Lion, Mail.app has removed its Notes capabilities in preference of the Notes.app. This Notes folder is used (if enabled) only in Notes.app on Mountain Lion and iOS 5+.

**What you can do is rename it something other then "Notes"**. You can change it to something like "Notes1" or "My Notes", and it will then appear as a normal folder in Mail.app (as an example).

Comment: This is what I was fearing. I find it weird to have to do this, but this is an expected outcome.